# Что делать, если файл отображается как UnversionedFiles и вылетает ошибка java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, android-studio, файлы, runtime

При запуске приложения возникает следующая ситуация:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И возникает ошибка:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.posts, PID: 2528
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.posts/com.example.posts.postsList}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase com.example.posts.DBHelper.getReadableDatabase()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase com.example.posts.DBHelper.getReadableDatabase()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.posts.postsList.onCreate(postsList.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Класс postsList:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class postsList extends Activity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private DBHelper mDataBaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_posts_list);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_num);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        if(this.mDataBaseHelper == null){
            this.mDataBaseHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        }

        SQLiteDatabase db = mDataBaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String sql = "select name, text from text";
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{});
        List<TextRow> myDataset = new ArrayList<>();
        if (c != null) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    int idId= c.getColumnIndex("_id");
                    int idName= c.getColumnIndex("name");
                    int idText= c.getColumnIndex("text");
                    myDataset.add(new TextRow(c.getInt(idId),c.getString(idName),c.getString(idText)));
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
            c.close();
        }

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(myDataset);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        if(this.mDataBaseHelper == null){
            this.mDataBaseHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        }
        db = mDataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("insert into text (_id,name,text)values(1,'MyFirstName','MyFirstText')");
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, из-за чего это может быть и что с эти делать

Comment: DBHelper.getReadableDatabase()' on a null object reference

Comment: @ Style-7, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить

Comment: выяснить причину почему объект равен нулю

Comment: @ Style, а какие могут быть тому причины?

Comment: Это служебный файл идеи/студии - лично я их добавляю в игнор, в репозитории они не нужны. А причина ошибки в том, что вы забыли инициализировать ссылку на `DBHelper` до обращения к ней в строке `32` класса `postsList`.

Comment: @woesss, подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать (никак не могу сообразить), код класса я добавил в вопрос

Comment: Странность какая-то: по коду у вас не должно быть этой ошибки. Пробуйте сделать rebuild проекта, принудительную остановку приложения, чистку кешей - что-то из этого должно помочь.